# TWS API request in Python blocked by Windows Firewall and Site-to-Site VPN issues despite successful RDP and ping

Tags: windows, vpn, firewall, tws

I am facing two issues related to the TWS API in Python while trying to establish communication between different computers.

1. Local LAN communication issue with Windows Firewall enabled: In a local LAN setup, when the client's Windows Firewall is enabled, the host detects the linking attempt, but the client experiences a timeout error. I have tried opening the API port in the client's firewall settings, but none of my attempts have been successful. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Can you suggest how to configure the Windows Firewall settings to allow the TWS API requests to pass through?
2. Site-to-Site VPN communication issue despite successful RDP and ping: In a similar scenario, the client is connected through a site-to-site VPN. In this case, even when I disable the client's Windows Firewall, the communication still does not work. It appears as if the client is in the local LAN and also has the Windows Firewall enabled as in scenario one. I have tried configuring the firewall policy for the VPN and the LAN between the computers, but it still doesn't work. Interestingly, I can successfully establish a remote desktop connection and ping between computers in the LAN and the other side of the site-to-site VPN, which makes me believe that the firewall policy should be fine. Has anyone dealt with TWS API requests in a site-to-site VPN setup where RDP and ping work fine? What additional configuration steps or considerations are necessary to establish communication between the host and client?

Any help or suggestions on either of these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!